# Convert PDF to XML using PYTHON -> Exception :TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, pdfminer

I have a python code which should convert PDF file to XML file ,  It's an incomplete code. But even though is not getting invoked . Can anyone please check this.

```
 from io import BytesIO

import pdfminer.converter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def get_xml_py2(file_path):
    in_fp = BytesIO()
    lstRtn = []
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as x:
        in_fp.write(x.read())

    laparams = LAParams(all_texts=True)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(in_fp):
        outfp = BytesIO()
        device = pdfminer.converter.XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=laparams)
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        lstRtn.append(outfp.getvalue())
        device.close()
        outfp.close()

        in_fp.close()

    return lstRtn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = get_xml_py2('Sample.pdf')
```

Am getting error :
[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Zrh.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error raised, or nothing at all happening?

Comment: nothing is happening @Amiga500 even Hi is not getting printed

Comment: After trying to run it, if you type get_xml_py2 into the console does it acknowledge it as a function handle?

Have you tried inserting breakpoint() at first line of main, then stepping manually from there?

Comment: I will try now . @Amiga500

Comment: Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.6777.50)

Process finished with exit code 0  ............ This is what am getting @Amiga500

Comment: Tried it here, getting a "GeneratorExit" on line 0 of the get_xml_py2  function... which is 'cos of your yield line

Comment: Is there any alternate for that , Since am new to this am not getting it .,

Answer (score 0):

Amend as below

```
def get_xml_py2A(file_path):
    print("hi")
    in_fp = BytesIO()
    lstRtn = []
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as x:
        in_fp.write(x.read())


        laparams = LAParams(all_texts=True)
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(in_fp):
            outfp = BytesIO()
            device = pdfminer.converter.XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=laparams)
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            interpreter.process_page(page)
            lstRtn.append(outfp.getvalue())            
            device.close()
            outfp.close()
 
        in_fp.close()
        
    return lstRtn
```

Comment: self.outfp.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'  ...... Am getting this error

Comment: ?? Don't understand your comment.

When you call your function from main, it should now give you a return. Assign that return then use print() on it.

You could iterate through the list returned and use decode() on each, will add that as edit.

Comment: Updated the Question, And attached error screenshot

Comment: have you retained the 'rb' in the with open line?

Comment: Yeah , I did that too